# wordpress expose menus to the rest api

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

Hi I'm trying to expose the WordPress menus to the rest api, but I want to make it generic, so I can crate expose any menus with the same code, but something is wrong with my code, t always show Json.pase error, I don't know how to solve this.

here is my code.

```
//define all the menu positions I need
$menus = array(
  'main-menu' =>  __( 'Main Menu' ),
  'other-menu' =>  __( 'Other Menu' )
);

function register_menus() {
  //register the menus in the backend
  global $menus;
  register_nav_menus($menus);
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_menus' );


add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    // create custom route to expose the menus
    register_rest_route( 'wp_ang/v1', '/menu', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'get_menu_items',
      )
    );
  }
);

function get_menu_items() {
    // callback to get menus and its items
    global $menus;
    $rest_menu = [];
    foreach ($menus as $key => $value){
      $menu_name = $key;
      $menu_location = get_nav_menu_locations( );
      $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $menu_location[$menu_name] );
      $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu->term_id );
    }
    return $menus;
}
```

Then I have this error as a result:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of
>   the JSON data

Comment: Have you tried to `json_encode();` the response? I find that JSON/API does not like the serialized data that WordPress saves.

Comment: @vars, yes I tried

Comment: Are you able to dump or log what the response data looks like?

Comment: Try entering yourhost/wp-json/wp_ang/v1/menu into your browser's address  bar. Although the result from the server is not HTML the browser will display it as plain text. It should be JSON but in your case it is not but what is it?

Comment: @user8262086 and @vars thanks for your tips,, I have already done, seems that if no element assigned to the menu, the menu don´t exists so... an `if (isset($menu_location[$menu_name]))` solve my problem